# Cannot create connection between two routers in same VLAN via switch

Tags: cisco, router, vlan, cisco-catalyst, dot1q

I currently have a Cisco 2960-24TT switch (switch1) and a Cisco 1841 router (router1) that form part of my core network connecting other VLANs and devices. The two ports on router1 have been configured with sub-interfaces i.e. router on a stick.
Having acquired a new router, Cisco C892FSP-K9 (router2) that comes with 10 Gigabit ports, I attempted to create a point-to-point network between router1 and router2 through switch1. The new VLAN, VLAN252 is in the IP space 10.10.252.100/30 has its IP address 10.10.252.101 assigned to router1, with users from other network able to PING it.
I've been unable to directly assign an IP address to router2's interfaces as they are Layer2 ports. Instead, I have created VLANs, one of which in VLAN252 with IP 10.10.252.102.
I have attempted the following modes, none of which have worked to enable a connection on VLAN252 between router1 and router2 through the switch:

1. Port Fa0/8 on switch1 in access mode with VLAN252 - Port Gi7 on router2 in access mode with VLAN252
2. Port Fa0/8 on switch1 in trunk mode with ALL VLANs allowed - Port Gi7 on router2 in trunk mode with ALL VLANs allowed

Snippets of config from router2 and switch1 on scenario number2 are pasted below:

```
r2#show ip int gi7 
... 
interface GigabitEthernet7  
switchport access vlan 252  
no ip address
r2#show ip int vlan252
...
Vlan252                    10.10.252.102   YES NVRAM  up                    up

s1#show vlan
...
252  r1-r2-ptp                active    Fa0/8
```

None of these have modes seem to enable a connection to router2.
What configurations can be done on the switch1 and router2 ports to enable a connection?[image: network diagram]

Comment: Please provide full configurations for all devices.

Comment: The router C892FSP-K9 does not have a 10Gig port, im afraid.

Comment: noone mentioned anything about 10G here, whats mentioned here is Gigabit Ports, 10 of them @MarioJost

Comment: Share configuration of R1..